# Format the data to generate linear regression in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, linear-regression, sql-server-2016

We are generating the following output from an SQL query for each product which is sent as an parameter

```
+-------------+---------------+-----------------+
| Quarterwise | Ship_Quantity | Failed_Quantity |
+-------------+---------------+-----------------+
| Q4-2008     |             0 |               1 |
| Q1-2009     |             0 |              28 |
| Q2-2009     |             0 |              22 |
| Q3-2009     |             0 |             289 |
| Q4-2009     |             0 |             121 |
| Q1-2010     |         11000 |             124 |
| Q2-2010     |             0 |               5 |
| Q3-2010     |             0 |               0 |
| Q4-2010     |             0 |               2 |
| Q1-2011     |             0 |              16 |
| Q2-2011     |             0 |              18 |
| Q3-2011     |             0 |               4 |
| Q4-2011     |             0 |               3 |
| Q1-2012     |             0 |              21 |
| Q2-2012     |             0 |              10 |
| Q3-2012     |             0 |               2 |
| Q4-2012     |             0 |               4 |
| Q1-2013     |          8500 |              10 |
| Q2-2013     |             0 |               5 |
| Q3-2013     |             0 |               2 |
| Q4-2013     |             0 |               4 |
| Q1-2014     |             0 |              12 |
| Q2-2014     |             0 |               4 |
| Q3-2014     |             0 |               6 |
| Q4-2014     |             0 |               7 |
+-------------+---------------+-----------------+
```

Question here is I need to convert the data from the above to the below format

- This product has a mean time of four quarters for failure hence we
  need to pick up four quarters data of ship quantity in independent
  variable s1 s2 s3 s4  and for dependent variable Fn we need to pickup
  the data of failure quantity from fifth quarter(note: Mean time is
  different for each component)
- We need to go through each quarters to transform the above data to the format below in order to generate the linear regression equation 
  using the output.

  ```
  +-------------------------------+------------------+
  |       Ship Quantity           | Failure Quantity |      
  +-------+-------+-------+-------+------------------+
  |   s1  |  s2   |   s3  |   s4  |        Fn        |
  +-------+-------+-------+-------+------------------+
  | Q4-08 | Q1-09 | Q2-09 | Q3-09 |              121 |
  | Q1-09 | Q2-09 | Q3-09 | Q4-09 |              124 |
  | Q2-09 | Q3-09 | Q4-09 | Q1-10 |              5   |
  +-------+-------+-------+-------+------------------+


  +----+----+-------+-------+-----+
  | s1 | s2 |  s3   |  s4   | Fn  |
  +----+----+-------+-------+-----+
  |  0 |  0 |     0 |     0 | 121 |
  |  0 |  0 |     0 |     0 | 124 |
  |  0 |  0 |     0 | 11000 |   5 |
  |  0 |  0 | 11000 |      0|  0  | 
  +----+----+-------+-------+-----+
  ```
- Data above just contains three row we need to generate like this till the end

Comment: What is your question here? You appear to have forgotten to ask one.

Comment: I need to generate the data for s1 s2 s3 s4 and Fn from quarterwise shipped quantity and failed quantity columns

Comment: But what is your question? That's what you want to do.

Comment: Yes I need to convert the data from the above format to the below one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your want to pass as a parameter number of quarters; then query can be built dynamically:

```
-- YOUR DATA:
-- ----------------------------------------------
select Quarterwise, Ship_Quantity, Failed_Quantity
into #Tab
from (  select 'Q4-2008' as Quarterwise, 0 as Ship_Quantity, 1 as Failed_Quantity
        union all select 'Q1-2009', 0,   28
        union all select 'Q2-2009', 0,   22
        union all select 'Q3-2009', 0,   289
        union all select 'Q4-2009', 0,   121
        union all select 'Q1-2010', 11000,124
        union all select 'Q2-2010', 0,   5
        union all select 'Q3-2010', 0,   0
        union all select 'Q4-2010', 0,   2
        union all select 'Q1-2011', 0,   16
        union all select 'Q2-2011', 0,   18 ) data

DECLARE @PARAMETER INT
SET @PARAMETER = 5

-- SOLUTION
-- ----------------------------------------------
DECLARE @QUERY1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @QUERY2 NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @QUERY1 = 
';with cte as
(
    select
        Quarterwise as Q,
        Ship_Quantity as SQ,
        Failed_Quantity as FQ,
        substring(Quarterwise,4,4)+substring(Quarterwise,2,1) as ord from #Tab
)
select
    T1.SQ as s1'

SET @QUERY2 = 
'
from
    cte T1'

DECLARE @i INT
DECLARE @istr NVARCHAR(4)
SET @i = 2
WHILE @i <= @PARAMETER
BEGIN
    SET @istr = cast(@i as varchar)
    SET @QUERY1 = @QUERY1 + ',
    T'+@istr+'.SQ as s'+@istr

    SET @QUERY2 = @QUERY2 + '
    cross apply (select top 1 * from cte T'+@istr+' where T'+@istr+'.ord > T'+cast(@i-1 as varchar)+'.ord order by ord asc) T'+@istr

    SET @i = @i + 1
END
SET @QUERY1 = @QUERY1 +',
    T'+@istr+'.FQ as Fn'    

-- RUN DYNAMIC QUERY
-- ----------------------------------------------
SET @QUERY1 = @QUERY1 + @QUERY2

EXEC sp_executesql @QUERY1


s1          s2          s3          s4          s5          Fn
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
0           0           0           0           0           121
0           0           0           0           11000       124
0           0           0           11000       0           5
0           0           11000       0           0           0
0           11000       0           0           0           2
11000       0           0           0           0           16
0           0           0           0           0           18





-- CLEAN
-- ----------------------------------------------
drop table #Tab
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-- YOUR DATA:
-- ----------------------------------------------
select Quarterwise, Ship_Quantity, Failed_Quantity
into #Tab
from (  select 'Q4-2008' as Quarterwise, 0 as Ship_Quantity, 1 as Failed_Quantity
        union all select 'Q1-2009', 0,   28
        union all select 'Q2-2009', 0,   22
        union all select 'Q3-2009', 0,   289
        union all select 'Q4-2009', 0,   121
        union all select 'Q1-2010', 11000,124
        union all select 'Q2-2010', 0,   5
        union all select 'Q3-2010', 0,   0
        union all select 'Q4-2010', 0,   2
        union all select 'Q1-2011', 0,   16
        union all select 'Q2-2011', 0,   18 ) data


-- SOLUTION
-- ----------------------------------------------
;with cte as
(
    select
        Quarterwise as Q,
        Ship_Quantity as SQ,
        Failed_Quantity as FQ,
        substring(Quarterwise,4,4)+substring(Quarterwise,2,1) as ord from #Tab
)
select
    T1.SQ as s1,
    T2.SQ as s2,
    T3.SQ as s3,
    T4.SQ as s4,
    T4.FQ as Fn
from
    cte T1
    cross apply (select top 1 * from cte T2 where T2.ord > T1.ord order by ord asc) T2
    cross apply (select top 1 * from cte T3 where T3.ord > T2.ord order by ord asc) T3
    cross apply (select top 1 * from cte T4 where T4.ord > T3.ord order by ord asc) T4


-- CLEAN
-- ----------------------------------------------
drop table #Tab

-- OUTPUT
-- ----------------------------------------------
--  s1          s2          s3          s4          Fn
--  ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
--  0           0           0           0           289
--  0           0           0           0           121
--  0           0           0           11000       124
--  0           0           11000       0           5
--  0           11000       0           0           0
--  11000       0           0           0           2
--  0           0           0           0           16
--  0           0           0           0           18
```

Comment: its use full to me but column s1 s2 s3 s4 is dynamic which will be sent through parameter, if it is 5 then the columns will be like s1 s2 s3 s4 s5 and Fn